# Exogenous/control varible not include in IV when runing reg3

Tags: econometrics, stata, instrumental-variables

I have the following two-equation system.
$$y_1=c_{10}+c_{11} y_2+c_{12} x_1+c_{12} x_3+e_1$$
$$y2=c_{20}+c_{21} y_{1}+c_{22} x_2+c_{23} x_3+e_2$$
where, $y_1$, $y_2$ are endogenous variables, $x_1$,$x_2$, and $x_3$ are exogenous variables, all Cs are coefficients.

I would like to use $x_1$, $x_2$ as IVs for $y_1$ and $y_2$ respectively, but excluding $x_3$ (it does not qualify as an IV, because it influences both $y_1$ and $y_2$).

I wonder how to specify the IVs in reg3. It seems to me reg3 treats all exogenous variables as IVs by default.